# Is it possible to nest snippets inside other snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate

Let's say that I have a snippet that inserts a comment like it was a heading. Something like this:

```
///////////////////////////]
// My Heading -------------]
```

And then I had a particular way that I wrote classes (e.x. the ordering of class members) and I wanted to use multiple instances of the previous "heading" snippet in multiple places inside this class. Something like:

```
///////////////////////////]
// PUBLIC METHODS ---------]
public doSomething() {}

///////////////////////////]
// PRIVATE METHODS --------]
private _doSomethingElse() {}
```

Is there a way that I could compose different snippets together where I'm not actually writing:

```
///////////////////////////]
// PRIVATE METHODS --------]
```

inside of my "class" snippet – and better yet, be able to pass the heading name `PUBLIC METHODS` as the value of a variable inside of the "heading" snippet?

As I create more and more snippets that use common elements within them and wanting to change something (like what headings look like), it would be nice to only have to make that change in one place and affect all the relevant snippets.